# grails domain class annotation not being pick up in a controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I created the following annotation:

```
public @interface NavAnnotation {

    boolean addToAdminMenu() default false;

}
```

... then try to annotate a domain class:

```
@NavAnnotation ( addToAdminMenu = true )
class Information {...}
```

... and do something with that in a controller:

```
def appDomainClasses = grailsApplication.domainClasses.findAll {
    it.class.isAnnotationPresent( NavAnnotation )

}
[ appDomainClasses : appDomainClasses ]
```

... but that annotated class is not getting picked up. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple things...

1.) Ensure that your annotation has a retention policy of `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.  The RUNTIME retention policy allows the annotation to be available for reflection at runtime.  So your interface should look like....

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NavAnnotation {
    boolean addToAdminMenu() default false;
}
```

2.) `grailsApplication.domainClasses` returns a `DefaultGrailsDomainClass` and not the actual class you want to preform reflections on.  Instead you want to access the underlining class using the getClazz() method like this....

```
def appDomainClasses = grailsApplication.domainClasses.findAll {
    it.getClazz().isAnnotationPresent( NavAnnotation )

}
```

I've tested to confirm that it works.  Enjoy!

-Thanks

Comment: ... just added
@Target( ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME ) but no joy

Comment: your target should be CLASS because your annotating a class.  Please show the results of a println of the annotations available at runtime.

Comment: ... when I try to use CLASS as target I get: No enum const java.lang.annotation.ElementType.CLASS in @java.lang.annotation.Target @ line 16, column 10. @Target( ElementType.CLASS ) ^ 1 error , ... printing out annotations gives me [], that's it

Comment: Sorry.  It's TYPE not CLASS (wrong lang).  I've updated my answer and confirmed that it works.  Use it.getClazz() instead of it.class